# Getting info from web page between <strong> TAGS

Tags: vb.net

So i am trying to get some text from a web page that is located between  tags. I have included an image that shows the text i am trying to get.
[highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mryJg.png)

the code i have currently is as follows although it is gathering other information as well which is not needed.

```
For Each ele As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.All
        If ele.GetAttribute("className").ToLower.Contains("cwybtn") Then
            Dim colourSource As String = ele.GetAttribute("innerText")
            'ListBox2.Items.Add(colourSource) 'Adds all .jpg images to the ListBox
            MsgBox(colourSource)
        End If
    Next
```

Has anyone got any ideas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why don't you try with tagName? you have an element from class name try to get the element from that element as tagName
hope this will help getElementsByTagName("strong")

Answer (score 0):

Ankit

thanks for that! I for got about tagname to be honest, i have now fixed it!

```
For Each strongTag As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("strong")
            MsgBox(strongTag.InnerText)
        Next
```